# Python: pandas data frame convert string and values into column category

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I would like to process with the grouped dataset below (the command lead to the below result is `df.groupby(['ids','category'])['counts'].sum()`)

```
ids|category|counts
1   A        3
2   B        5
3   A        1
    B        1
    C        1
4   C        3
```

What I am trying to get is below (every unique id with one row so that I can merge with another data table later):

```
ids|A_n|B_n|C_n
1   3    0   0
2   0    5   0
3   1    1   1
4   0    0   3
```

Is this possible? Any thoughts are welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: Try from your original dataframe: `pd.crosstab(df['ids'], df['category'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `unstack` and `fillna`

```
group_df.unstack('category').fillna(0)
```

Output

```
         counts          
category      A    B    C
ids                      
1           3.0  0.0  0.0
2           0.0  5.0  0.0
3           1.0  1.0  1.0
4           0.0  0.0  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem in a such simple and beautiful way!